# Xcode 11 running on Mojave fails despite Apple's documentation saying Mojave is supported

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13

I'm trying to get Xcode 11 to run on my Mojave mac to build for the minimum iOS requirement (iOS 13).
I deleted Xcode 10 because trying to upload to App Store, Xcode says: "you need a newer version of Xcode that targets iOS13+". The highest iOS I had available was 12.4.

I have tried several versions of Xcode 11.X . Currently downloading the earliest one. Every other version has NOT worked.

How can I tell what will work? Where is this documented?

Where is the mythical "GM seed 2" promised by the Apple poster, who says it will run on Mojave?

Apple's documentation claims Xcode 11 will run on Mojave but it does not.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

versions above Xcode11.4 require you to have macOS Catalina 10.15.2 on you Mac

[Xcode11.4 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_4-release-notes)

Mojave only supports upto Xcode 11.3.1

[Xcode11.3.1 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-11_3_1-release-notes)